# strtok not working well

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I have a problem. Believe me, I started using this strtok() function at 1 or 2AM. and it is 4:22AM now. >.<

The problem is this:
1. WHEN I INPUT A "blue", the three tokens are okay.
2. When I input a "red" or a "green", the three tokens are NULL :( .

```
const char s[2] = "~"; //for cutting;
char inData[100]; // Allocate some space for the string


char *token;
char *token2;
char *token3;
char x1[100];
char x2[100];
char x3[100];

char Comp(char* This) {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) // Don't read unless
                                   // there you know there is data
    {
        if(index < 99) // One less than the size of the array
        {
            inChar = Serial.read(); // Read a character
            inData[index] = inChar; // Store it
            index++; // Increment where to write next
        //  inData[index] = '\0'; // Null terminate the string
        }
    }

    token = strtok(inData, s);
    strcpy(x1,token);

    token2 = strtok(NULL, s);
    strcpy(x2,token2);

    token3 = strtok(NULL, s);
    strcpy(x3,token3);

    if (strcmp(x1,This)  == 0) {

        Serial.println(x1);
        Serial.println(x2);
        Serial.println(x3);

        for (int i=0;i<99;i++) {
            inData[i]=0;
        }
        index=0;
        return(0);
    }
    else {
        return(1);
    }
}
```

How I call the function Comp:

```
if(Comp("blue")==0){
    Serial.println("BLUE SELECTED");
    analogWrite(9, 0);
    analogWrite(10,255);
    analogWrite(11,255);

}

if(Comp("green")==0){
    Serial.println("GREEN SELECTED");
    analogWrite(10,0);
    analogWrite(11,255);
    analogWrite(9,255); 

}

if(Comp("red")==0){
    Serial.println("RED SELECTED");
    analogWrite(10,255);
    analogWrite(11,0);
    analogWrite(9,255); 

}
```

OUTPUTS:
when I input: "blue~lalalalal~kakakakaekkewew"
it outputs:
blue
lalalalal
kawawawawewew
blue selected

when I input: "red~123~321
it outputs:
red

red selected

when I input: "green~123~321"
it outputs
green

green selected

Comment: Your serial read operation never terminates the buffer after the loop breaks. Put `inData[index] = 0;` after it finishes please. That, assuming `index` is actually initialized to `0` on inception.

Comment: Proper indentation would help readability a lot. Especially with this much code involved.

Comment: thanks for the reply sirs! for sir WhozCraig: I've attached this picture: https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1/1796613_10201504171471088_2143310897_n.jpg    i really need the two strings in the last two tokens.

Comment: My manpage on strtok has this in its BUG section: "Avoid using these functions."

Comment: set index=0 on entry to the comp function. As pasted, this code will work for the first if block only. in this case "blue". If you copy paste the green block above, then it should start working for green and stop working for blue...

Comment: thanks for the answers guys! I've solved it! sir WhozCraig and sir rakeshdn's answers didn't work. :(. What I did is I modified the way of reading the data serially. Wait, I'll post the answer. Right now, I feel that I just wasted my 5 hours debugging this. I feel so dumb lol. so much regrets, I could have done many more things. grrrr

Answer (score 0):

this is the way I solved the bug.
changed the way I receive the data.

```
char Comp(char* This) {

while(Serial.available()) {
  inChar = Serial.read();
  inData.concat(inChar);
 }

  strcpy(inData2, inData.c_str());
   token = strtok(inData2, s);
        strcpy(x1,token);

            token = strtok(NULL, s);
          strcpy(x2,token);

              token = strtok(NULL, s);
              strcpy(x3,token);

if (strcmp(x1,This)  == 0) {

Serial.println(x1);
Serial.println(x2);
Serial.println(x3);

   inData = "";
   inChar = '\0';
    return(0);
}
else {
return(1);
}

}
```